# TypeError: Python unit testing using mock

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, python-unittest.mock

I am trying to test a function using python mock.

## Foo.py

```
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=db_state.engine))
@use_kwargs({
    'user_id': fields.Integer(location='json', required=True)
})
def create_user(user_id):
    with session as s:
        try:
            result = user_dao.create_user(s, user_id)
            return json.dumps(result), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
        except SQLAlchemyError:
            result = {"Fatal": "Id not found"}
            return json.dumps(result), 404, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

The unitest for this method is :

## test.py

```
class CreateUserTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("user_dao.create_user")
    @patch("flask.request")
        def test_create_user(self, mock_request, mock_create_user):
            mock_create_user.side_effect = SQLAlchemyError
            response, code, content = foo.create_user()
    
            multiple assert statements go here.
```

The stacktrace is not much very helping here. May be I am missing the obvious. Here's it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/binlib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/some/path/test.py", line 6, in test_create_user
    response, code, content = foo.create_user()
  File "/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webargs-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/webargs/core.py", line 434, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/some/path/foo.py", line 8, in create_user
    result = user_dao.create_user(s, user_id)
  File "/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1118, in _mock_call
    raise effect
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (1 given)
```

I did check the code for the mock.py and cannot spot what is going wrong here.

Comment: This line in the traceback: ` response, code, content = sample_batches.create_batch()` and this line in your listed `test.py`: `response, code, content = foo.create_user()` don't seem to match. Can you please confirm your traceback is indeed from that *exact* piece of code?

Comment: @Evert: My bad.